# How to select number with LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a bunch of products, and a bunch of category pages. One product can be in multiple categories. So in my database I have a products table with a "categories" column. In this column I store the ID's of all the categories that the current product is stored in, its a string seperated with semicolons.

Example:    `1;5;23;35;49;`.

When I browse to Category Page ID  5, I want to see all products that have `5;` in its categories-column. I currently do this by

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories LIKE "%".category.";%"
```

The problem is that this matches more than just 5. It matches `15;` or `25;` aswell.

So questions:

1. How do I make sure that I only select the number I want? If category is "5" I do not want it to match 15, 25, 35 and so on.
2. Maybe this is a very bad way of storing the category-ids. Do you have any suggestions of a different way of storing what products that belong to what category?

Comment: Well, there's your problem right there

Comment: Read about normalization in databases (just google _1NF_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers/comments to your two questions:

1. The only way I can think of that you could do this without modifying your schema (see #2) is to use a MySQL regular expression but this is really not a good idea. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for documentation though
2. You are right - this is not a good way to store categories. What you want is a join also known as a junction table (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). One way would be to have three tables: `product`, `category`, and a `product_categories` table. Product and category would have a unique ID as you already have and the product_categories table would have two columns: product_id and category_id. If product 1 belongs to categories 10 and 11, you would have two rows in the product_categories table: 1,10 and 1,11.

I can elaborate if you need more help but this should get you started in re-architecting your database (more) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned that a junction table is the right way to design the database.  SQL has a very nice data structure for storing lists.  It is not called a "string", it is called a "table".

But, sometimes one is stuck with data in this format and needs to work with it.  In that case, the key is to put the delimiters on both side to prevent the problem you are having:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE concat(';', categories) LIKE "%;".category.";%"
```

Your list already ends in a semicolon, so that is not necessary.

Another more typical MySQL solution is `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE find_in_set(category, replace(categories, ';', ',') > 0;
```

It is designed for comma-delimited lists.  Odd that MySQL supports such a function when storing lists this way is generally a bad idea, but it does.  Still, a junction table is better for performance reasons (and for other reasons).

Answer (score -2):

You can try changing your like criteria to "%;".category.";%"

Comment: That would not match the first number in the string. For example 1;2;3;4;. It would not match 1;